# Dynamically get all ul li elements from html .NET

Tags: c#

Iam scrapping HTML for one of my projects. I have a html list ul li tag elements in it.
I would like to grab all the li elements within that ul. In some case the ul element may not e there and in some cases the might be only one li.

How do I handle this and grab this content?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). You can use a fairly straightforward XQuery expression to get the `<li>` elements if they exist.